# On Check one input gets disabled and the other gets enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm coding a form which gets the value for some search process .. I'm coding two text fields for the user to give the input on any one of  them.But only one of them would enable at a time .. user can chose the option by checking check box. by default one of the field should b enable, when the check-box is checked it(the one which was initially enable) gets disabled and other gets enabled, and vice versa when the check-box is unchecked.

Here `is` the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/awBvq/224/

Comment: Fix the link and please give us the relevant HTML and javascript in your question

Comment: And where is your problem/what's your question? We **don't do the coding for you**.

Comment: OK, I see your fiddle, but your description and your fiddle don't match. Your fiddle has both fields enabled. What do you *want* to have happen?

Comment: Who is going to understand that GUI? Maybe you should choose for two radiobuttons instead of a checkbox.

Comment: @pjmorse you can see this fiddl now http://jsfiddle.net/awBvq/224 
on check one should get enble other dissable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix your problem

HTML :

```
<input type="text" name="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="" />
<input type="text" name="" disabled="'disabled'"/>
```

JS :

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).prev().attr('disabled','disabled');
         $(this).next().removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $(this).next().attr('disabled','disabled');
        $(this).prev().removeAttr('disabled');

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It could have been done simpler, but this is just a hint:

```
if($("#CheckBox").is(":checked"))
{
  $("#Field1").attr("disabled","disabled");
  $("#Field2").removeAttr("disabled");
}
else
{
  $("#Field1").removeAttr("disabled");
  $("#Field2").attr("disabled","disabled");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple logic:

(1) By default disable any one of the textbox.

(2) Using [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) or [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), check whether anyone is disabled.

(3) if so, enable it and disable the other else vice versa.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="" disabled/>  <!--By default it is disabled-->
<input type="checkbox" name="" />
<input type="text" name="" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(':checkbox').change(function () {
    if ($(this).prev().is(':disabled')) {
        $(this).prev().removeAttr('disabled');
        $(this).next().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $(this).next().removeAttr('disabled');
        $(this).prev().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/awBvq/231/)